# Control the recursion when computing a sum that it stops at a certain expression

Tags: haskell

I want to compute the sum of  [ Sum(m+i)^n from i=m to n ]. How can i stop the recursion when n has reached m and not when the recursion hits zero?
for example some inputs

```
Main>Sum 0 1
0
Main>Sum 1 1
1
Main>Sum 0 3
36
Main>Sum 1 5
12200
Main>Sum 3 4
3697
```

this is what i came up with, but it wont work when m = n and also my results are not correct.

```
sum :: Integer->Integer->Integer             
sum m n
|  (m<0 && n <0) = 0
|  n<m =0
|  otherwise = (sum m (n-1)) + ((m+n)^n)
```

Comment: `sum [(m + i) ^ n | i <- [m..n]]`?

Comment: Change ```| n <m = 0``` to ```| n <= m = 0```

Comment: By the way, why are you lying to us? `Sum 3 4`  will most probably **not** output 3697, and it certainly wont run `sum`

Comment: @Ingo "will most probably not output 3697" have you actually tried this sum?, i used @Ryan♦ 's list comprehension and it worked. im such a liar lel

Comment: @LeonidasB You wrote `Sum` , not `sum` , that's why.

Comment: @Ingo yeap youre right on this, but its an out of context detail as i explained the sum i wanted to compute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the mathematical fact that

```
(Sum f(x) from x=n to m) = f(n) + (Sum f(x) from x=n+1 to m) when n < m
```

and that

```
(Sum f(x) from x=m to m) = f(m)
```

Also, negative n or m is an error. Let's translate that directly into Haskell:

```
sum :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
sum f n m
  | (n < 0 || m < 0) = error "Negative limits"
  -- The first rule above
  | n < m = f n + sum f (n + 1) m
  -- The second rule above
  | n == m = f m
```

The above function is recursion on a general summation, given as a function from `i` to the summand. To get the actual function you wanted:

```
yourFunction :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
yourFunction n m = sum (\i -> (n + i)^m) n m
```

Note how the recursion works in the first rule above. The recursive call `sum f (n + 1) m` means that it *increases* n until it equals m, adding up all the intermediate results.